# Kill thread of the System process

Tags: windows-10, drivers, process, cpu-usage

I want to kill a specific thread that consumes about the 30 percent of the time of my processor. Here is the screenshots of processhacker:

[image: screen1]

This occurs sometimes when the driver [EXT2FSD](http://www.ext2fsd.com/) that allows me to read ext partitions tries to read a usb with the filesystem corrupted. So the process runs in background and i can't stop it (even disconnecting the drive).

[image: screen2]

There is a way to stop the specific thread in windows?

Comment: Use a virtual machine with Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certain protected processes - those critical to the stability of the OS - cannot be modified by user-mode programs, even those running as administrator or as the `SYSTEM` account. Therefore, you cannot kill or even suspend a thread of the System process without writing a kernel-mode driver. The Kill button on [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx)'s Threads tab would stop the thread if it could, but if you try, you'll find that it can't.

Even if you could kill the thread, you shouldn't. Threads can hold exclusive locks on resources while they do something important. If a thread died in the middle of doing something like that, all other threads in the process would likely be left with that resource in an inconsistent state. Further reading: [Understanding the consequences of WAIT_ABANDONED](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050912-14/?p=34253). This is bad enough in a standard user-mode process, but doing it to the OS kernel would be disastrous.

If you want to stop this driver from using your computer's resources, you should uninstall the driver as you would any other.

Comment: I understand that the thread is protected, but even i request restart the computer, this thread block me to do that(and shutdown too). I need to read ext partitions so my solution is to install another driver thay allows me to do that. Do you know another driver?

Comment: @ArieCwHat It seems to be possible to make Ext2Fsd not start on system boot using its management tool, if that helps. There are a couple other options for ext mounting in [this guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/112888/3-ways-to-access-your-linux-partitions-from-windows/).

Comment: yes, but that is not my problem. When i connect a correct formatted ext usb drive, it works perfectly, but when not, the most obvious is to go to the drive managenemt and format the drive, but when i start the drive management,  it remains loading infinitely, so the ext driver start to use cpu time like crazy. :) i think this s a bug on the driver so i will try the other options. thanks